# QML, create LineSeries at runtime

Tags: qt, charts, qml, lineseries

My goal is to have a QML `ChartView` with a variable number of `LineSeries` added to it during runtime.  It is unknown how many `LineSeries` will need to be added until a user selects and loads a file with the data in it.

I tried to create all of the `LineSeries` inside a `Repeater`, with no luck.  I suspect it's because `ChartView` doesn't know what to do with a bunch of `Item`'s.  It's not possible to have the `Repeater` create `LineSeries` directly since a `Repeater` doesn't work on `QObject`'s:

```
Repeater {
    model: numberOfColumnsInModel / 2

    delegate: Item {
        LineSeries {
            id: lineSeries
            axisX: xAxis
            axisY: yAxis

            VXYModelMapper {
                id: modelMapper
                model: lineChart.model //Reimplemented QAbstractTableModel
                xColumn: index * 2
                yColumn: index * 2 + 1
            }

            onHovered: {
                console.log("Do something...");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In the examples I see online, each `LineSeries` is hard-coded--once for each line in the `ChartView`--and not useful to me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use <s>force</s> documentation, Luke.
In the example below random count of lines with random count of points are created at starting up:

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0
import QtCharts 2.1

Window {
    id: window1
    title: "Chart test"
    visible: true
    width: 600
    height: 400

    ChartView {
        id: chart
        anchors.fill: parent
        axes: [
            ValueAxis{
                id: xAxis
                min: 1.0
                max: 10.0
            },
            ValueAxis{
                id: yAxis
                min: 0.0
                max: 10.0
            }
        ]
        Component.onCompleted: {
            var seriesCount = Math.round(Math.random()* 10);
            for(var i = 0;i < seriesCount;i ++)
            {
                var series = chart.createSeries(ChartView.SeriesTypeLine, "line"+ i, xAxis, yAxis);
                series.pointsVisible = true;
                series.color = Qt.rgba(Math.random(),Math.random(),Math.random(),1);
                series.hovered.connect(function(point, state){ console.log(point); }); // connect onHovered signal to a function
                var pointsCount = Math.round(Math.random()* 20);
                var x = 0.0;
                for(var j = 0;j < pointsCount;j ++)
                {
                    x += (Math.random() * 2.0);
                    var y = (Math.random() * 10.0);
                    series.append(x, y);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: While this will work, it neglects to demonstrate how I could use the `onHovered` signal for each series like I showed in my question.  AFAIK, you cannot connect to signals inside of JavaScript, but hopefully I just haven't found a way to do this.  If you can modify your answer demonstrating how to use the `onHovered` signal, I can accept this answer.

Comment: There is no problem to connect in JS. See [this](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-syntax-signals.html#connecting-signals-to-methods-and-signals) link for more info and my updated example.